# Sort List by another, incomplete list

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

Okay I might overthink something here. 
I try to sort a List by another List. Which works fine as long as another List contains all elements of List. 
What would be a good apprach, if another List is incomplete and I'd like to keep the remaining elements at the end of List?

here an example:

```
public class Column
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string Something;
    //...
}

public class Columns : IEnumerable<Column>
{
    private List<Column> columnList = new List<Column>;

    public void SortByName(List<Column> sortedIncompleteList)
    {
            var sorted = from incomplete in sortedIncompleteList
                         join current in columnList
                         on incomplete.FieldName equals current.FieldName 
                         select current;
            columnList = sorted.ToList();
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: since you know how to do it with complete list, start with excluding the missing elements with except. Then just stick these to the ordered list.

Comment: The sort logic is not clear. You want to order `columnList` by another list that is provided as method argument? So why don't you use `order by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i am oversimplifying it, but why don't you use `OrderBy` if you want to sort? You can use following logic to get the items first which are in both collection:

```
public void SortByName(List<Column> sortedIncompleteList)
{
    columnList = columnList
     .OrderByDescending(c => sortedIncompleteList.Any(c2 => c.FieldName == c2.FieldName))
     .ToList();
}
```

---

Update according to the comment: "but not in the order they actually appear in `sortedIncompleteList`":

```
public void SortByName(List<Column> sortedIncompleteList)
{
    columnList = columnList
       .OrderBy(c => {
           int index = sortedIncompleteList.FindIndex(c2 => c.FieldName == c2.FieldName);
           if (index == -1) return int.MaxValue;
           return index;
       })
       .ToList();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as the elements contained in `sortedIncompleteList` are returned first, but not in the order they actually appear in `sortedIncompleteList`...

Comment: @BarisAkar: have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the elements in your lists are unique, since `Column` has an `Id` field, because my solution will remove duplicates.

```
public class Columns : IEnumerable<Column>
{
    private List<Column> columnList = new List<Column>;

    public void SortByName(List<Column> sortedIncompleteList)
    {
            columnList = sortedIncompleteList.Intersect(columnList)
                            .Concat(columnList.Except(sortedIncompleteList)).ToList();
    }
    //...
}
```

`Intersect()`, `Concat()` and `Except()` will preserve ordering...

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
var ids = sortedIncompleteList.Select(li => li.Id).ToList();

var ordered = from element in columnList
              let index = ids.IndexOf(element.Id)
              orderby index < 0 ? columnList.Count : index
              select element;
```